# Suppress \unspace command to force biblatex to add spaces (DIN 1505)

Tags: spacing, biblatex, bibliographies

DIN 1505 requires breakable interword spaces in front of punctuation. A bibliography entry is supposed to look like this:

> ```
> Lastname1, Firstname1 ; Lastname2, Firstname2: Title : Subtitle [...]
> ```
>
> **^**                                                    **^**

I tried to accomplish this by redefining the `\multinamedelim` and `\subtitlepunct` commands. Unfortunately the `\addspace` in front of `\addsemicolon` respectively `\addcolon` doesn't show up in the resulting file. The reason for this is the `\unspace` command, which removes preceding whitespaces. It is implicitly executed by `\addspace`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
style=alphabetic,
backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@BOOK{Author2001,
  author = {Alastname, Afirstname},
  title = {Title},
    subtitle = {Subtitle},
  year = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

% Setup bibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addspace\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\begin{document}
Filler text \cite{Author2001}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

I found an example of a DIN 1505 style ([see here](https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505)). The author substituted `\addspace` with `\mbox{ }`. Unfortunately this is not officially supported by `biblatex`. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: In front of the colons and semicolons? This seems strange. However, the places where you'd like to have spaces are difficult to tell from your example; can you use a fixed width font for better showing them?

Comment: This looks really strange and I have not seen any journal using this format. DIN 1505 is supposed to be replaced with DIN ISO 690 which does not seem to include this format, so I would recommend using the updated version instead.

Comment: Yes, I meant the spaces in front of the colons and semicolons. I formated my example as code. That way a fixed font width is used and hopefully things become clearer.

Comment: @Alexander I think the style DIN 1505 is not all that unpopular. For example bibsonomy.org is able to export it. Anyway, I'm  supposed to us this style and not ISO 690. By the way, ISO 690 also has spaces in front of colons and semicolons!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just replace the `\addsemicolon`/`\addcolon` etc. commands by a plain `;` or `:` respectively, so `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}` becomes `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace;\addspace}`.
That way `biblatex` does not check for space preceding the punctuation mark, but neither will it check for preceding punctuation symbols as `\addsemicolon` would.

We can also delve a little bit deeper into the internals of `biblatex` and try and define our own space-preserving macros `\addsp<punct>`. Those macros are defined via `\blx@addsppunct`, which is essentially the macro `\blx@addpunct` with the `\unspace` commented out.

You now use `\addspsemicolon` and `\addspcolon` instead of `\addsemicolon` and `\addcolon` whenever you do not want the preceding space to disappear.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% see biblatex.sty for these macros
\blx@regimcs{%
  \addspsemicolon \addspcolon \addspcomma}
\def\blx@addsppunct#1{% <---- new name for spaced punctuation
  %\unspace <----- commented out
  \ifnum\blx@spacefactor<\blx@sf@threshold@low
    \csuse{blx@qp@#1}\csuse{abx@#1}%
  \else
    \ifnum\blx@spacefactor>\blx@sf@threshold@high
      \csuse{blx@qp@#1}\csuse{abx@#1}%
    \else
      \ifcsdef{blx@pp@\the\csname blx@sf@#1\endcsname @\blx@spacefactor}
        {\csuse{blx@qp@#1}\csuse{abx@#1}}
        {\csuse{blx@qp@#1}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@pq@#1}}

\protected\def\blx@imc@addspsemicolon{\blx@addsppunct{semicolon}}
\protected\def\blx@imc@addspcolon{\blx@addsppunct{colon}}
\protected\def\blx@imc@addspcomma{\blx@addsppunct{comma}}
\makeatother

% Set up bibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\addspsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multilistdelim}{\addspace\addspsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finallistdelim}{multilistdelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addspace\addspcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma ; Ryde, Ulf: „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P//Worman, Nancy: The Cast of Character : Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002]

*edit* Code modernised for `biblatex` 3.8 and newer. See the edit history for older versions.

Comment: I actually hoped that there is a switch in BibLaTeX in order to temporarily switch off the `\unspace`-cycle. Unfortunately it seems like there isn't. Nevertheless **THANKS** for the coding you did. Under these circumstances, your solution of defining new macros, is the best possible one.

Comment: @FrogThomas Well you could `\let\oldunspace\unspace \newcommand{\nounspace}{\let\unspace\relax} \newcommand{\dounspace}{\let\unspace\oldunspace}` and then use `\nounspace` and `\dounspace` to switch off all `\unspace` temporarily. Use it as in `\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\nounspace\addsemicolon\dounspace\adds‌​pace}`. You can then also define `\newcommand{\addspsemicolon}{\nounspace\addsemicolon\dounspace}` and use `\addspsemicolon` as above. This is essentially the poor man's version of a switch.

Comment: Using `egrep origtitle *` in the biblatex folder finds the mention in `biblatex1` but not `biblatex2`. Is this on purpose or just missed?

Comment: @Johannes_B Mhh, you will find that `\abx@dofields` looks different in `biblatex1` and `biblatex2`. In the former, all fields are listed, while in the latter we are referred to `\def\abx@dofields{\dolistcsloop{blx@biber@datamodel@fields}}`. I suppose `biblatex2`'s `origtitle` lives in `biblatex-dm.def`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Ah, all the internals are confusing. Working on the wikibook page on bibliographies right now.