# Thinspace before delimiter in citation

Tags: biblatex, delimiters

I want to edit the delimiter in the citation of my document. The MWE

```
% This is {MWE.tex} Created on 2017-06-12 by thymaro %

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace\addcolon\space}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption[Agricultural land use]{Agricultural land use \parencite[A34]{br11}}
    \label{tab:lu}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \toprule
        Land use & [ha] \\ \midrule
        arable land (total) &  951 654 \\
        of which soft wheat &  51 842 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with mwe.bib as follows

```
@techreport{br11,
address = {New Amsterdam},
author = {{blw -- Baldwin Locomotive Works}},
shortauthor = {blw},
institution = {{Institute for Bio Reports}},
pages = {460},
title = {{Bio Report 2011}},
url = {https://www.bioreport.com},
year = {2011}
}
```

produces

[image: where I am at now]

and I would like the citation to more resemble

[image: what I wish for]

with thinspaces (or similar) before and after the colon delimiter, as in

> [author] [year] thinspace colon thinspace [pages]

How would I achieve such a result?

Comment: A different issue: Are you sure that the entry type `@techreport` is appropriate for the `br11` entry?

Comment: `\add...` is designed to delete the previous space/punctuation and replace it.  So perhaps you want `\addthinspace:\addthinspace`, but one would need to see more use cases to be sure.

Comment: `biblatex` does not like spaces before punctuation and tries hard to suppress them. See also [Suppress \unspace command to force biblatex to add spaces (DIN 1505)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130448/35864). David's solution here works brilliantly as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by @moewe in the comments below `\addthinspace`, `\addnbthinspace`, and `\addspace` are removed by `biblatex` at the start of the `postnote`. Instead use `\thinspace`, which uses a `\kern` and is not removed.

So `\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\thinspace\addcolon\thinspace}` will do what you want.

Comment: Interestingly this does not work for `\addthinspace` before `\addcolon`, because `\addthinspace` is a `\hskip` which is removed by `\unspace` while standard `\thinspace` uses a `\kern` that is not removed.

Comment: @DavidPurton: Can you rewrite your "answer" with some authority rather than stating it as a question? Despite the up-votes, it seems like you're guessing here...

Comment: First thing I did, when I read this answer, was try it, expecting to post the erroneous result here. As it turns out, it works (of course, it does). I had thought I had tried something with `\thinspace`, but it seems I hadn't or made some mistake when trying it. Anyways, many thanks.